# Redirect with RewriteCond not works correctly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Where Im doying mistake:

Not works:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1\.sk/en/(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://domain2.com/en [R=301,L]
```

Not works with backslash:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1\.sk\/en\/(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://domain2.com/en [R=301,L]
```

Works without /en/:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1\.sk(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://domain2.com/en [R=301,L]
```

Another think / variable $1 not works too (nothing return):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1\.sk(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

...or does exists any way to debug it?

Comment: We cannot say "where you do a mistake". You did neither tell us what you _want_ to do, nor what _is_ actually happening.

Comment: And yes, there are _two_ things you _always_ should keep in mind when working on rewriting rules: 1. _always_ first take a loko into your http servers error log. That is where you usually can _read_ what the issue is instead of having to guess. And 2. there is something called "rewrite logging". Comes in very handed and is documented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%{HTTP_HOST}` matches only domain part in question. For matching parts of URI you can use `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable OR else use `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1\.sk [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(en)(/.*)?$ http://domain2.com/$1$2 [R=301,L,NC]
```

`$1, $2` etc are captured from `RewriteRule`.

Comment: This example is working :-) ! But :-( the problem is $1 variable, which is not captured or empty.

Comment: What is exact URL are you entering and what it should be redirected to?

Comment: I deleted the browser cache and the second example is working perfectly! Thank you veeeery veeeery much.

Comment: And only latest question, is it possible do the same thing, depend not on rewrited /en/ option in url, but from ?lang=en parameter? Reason is, I would like to hide /en/ from url.

Comment: Use use: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^en=` for that. However if you can't make it work don't hesitate to pose a new question.

Comment: I was created new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36741308/how-to-remove-language-alias-from-url-with